# Блок отображается не там где надо

Tags: css, html5, вёрстка, html

Скорее всего он не видит див с id Sea. Надо чтобы он отображался после блока sea.
P.S. это блоки P (P Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia tempore ex delectus rerum optio sapiente magnam ullam ipsum voluptate, maxime./p).
CSS и HTML код:

```css
/* id */
#sea {
 z-index: -1;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 margin-bottom: -50%;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: url(http://snim.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5.jpg)no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% auto;
}
/* class */
.header-content {
 background-color: #00060C;
 height: inherit;
 width:25%;
 border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #ffffff;
}
/*tag*/
body {
 margin: 0px;
}
header {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100;
}
p {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>#док</title>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="header-content">
   <span id="howIdo">Как я это делал?</span>
  </div>
 </header>
 <div id="sea"></div>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia tempore ex delectus rerum optio sapiente magnam ullam ipsum voluptate, maxime.</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia tempore ex delectus rerum optio sapiente magnam ullam ipsum voluptate, maxime.</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia tempore ex delectus rerum optio sapiente magnam ullam ipsum voluptate, maxime.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Блок отображается не там где надо" - какой блок?

Comment: <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia tempore ex delectus rerum optio sapiente magnam ullam ipsum voluptate, maxime.</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia tempore ex delectus rerum optio sapiente magnam ullam ipsum voluptate, maxime.</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia tempore ex delectus rerum optio sapiente magnam ullam ipsum voluptate, maxime.</p>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

замени в стилях блока `#sea`  `position:absolute` на `position:relative`. блоки будут отступать. Вообще это довольно популярная проблема для новичков. Я б посоветовал почитать про позиционирование и потоки. статей  достаточно много.
самое первое что находишь:

Абсолютное позиционирование делает две вещи:

```
Элемент исчезает с того места, где он должен быть и позиционируется заново. Остальные элементы, располагаются так, как будто этого элемента никогда не было.
Координаты top/bottom/left/right для нового местоположения отсчитываются от ближайшего позиционированного родителя, т.е. родителя с позиционированием, отличным от static. Если такого родителя нет – то относительно документа.
```

Answer (score 1):

Если проблема в том, что не видно блок `#sea`, то это проблема в ссылке на картинку.(Избегайте использования кирилицы).
Если вам нужно, что бы абзацы шли после блока с фоном (`#sea`), то уберите у блока `#sea` свойство `position: absolute`.

P.S. Задавайте вопрос нормально, что бы другие участники могли понять какую проблему вы пытаетесь решить.

```css
/* id */
#sea {
 z-index: -1;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 margin-bottom: -50%;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/37403/bora-bora-french-polynesia-sunset-ocean.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350") no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% auto;
}
/* class */
.header-content {
 background-color: #00060C;
 height: inherit;
 width:25%;
 border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #ffffff;
}
/*tag*/
body {
 margin: 0px;
}
header {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100;
}
p {
 display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>#док</title>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="header-content">
   <span id="howIdo">Как я это делал?</span>
  </div>
 </header>
 <div id="sea"></div>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia tempore ex delectus rerum optio sapiente magnam ullam ipsum voluptate, maxime.</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia tempore ex delectus rerum optio sapiente magnam ullam ipsum voluptate, maxime.</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia tempore ex delectus rerum optio sapiente magnam ullam ipsum voluptate, maxime.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не я про блоки p. Убрал Absolute и помогло. Уже понял

Comment: Кстати тогда как решить свойство height не отображается в процентах? Раз способ с absolute не подходит.